# Ionic 2 http.get android 500

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic2

I try to make a http.get in ionic 2. it works fine on ios but not in android.

```
checkHTTP() {
  console.log('checkHTTP');
  return this.http.get('http://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/version', {}, {})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

this is the result in android:

> Object {status: 500, error: "There was an error with the request"}
>   error
>   :
>   "There was an error with the request"
>   status
>   :
>   500

Here are some infos from ionic

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 3.5.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 2.0.2
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score -1):

the answer is simple. My Test-Device lost internet-connection. But WLAN-Status looks normal :-(
But ist a little bit strange, i think 500 means an Server-Error